# sticky top nav creates a scrollbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a page with a sticky navbar at the top, and I gave the navbar a height 50px, and pushed the body using padding-top of 50px but now the page has a scrollbar. How can I get rid of the scrollbar?

[jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/mqs13o0b/)

Here is HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Navigation bar section -->
        <nav class="navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
/* top navigation bar 
 * ------------------ */
 .navbar-fixed-top {
    top: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1030;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    clear: both;
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    float: left;
    background-color: #FF9933;
}
.navbar-nav {
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why are you trying to reinvent Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @TimLewis Just because he use his own CSS ? Bootstrap is just a tool for some instances.

Comment: @Danko I agree, it's just strange that he knows the syntax perfectly for Bootstrap but is still trying to use his own CSS. Again, just an observation.

Comment: @TimLewis: I wanted to customize my site very specifically and seeing how enormous bootstrap css is, I though I should start form scratch. I am looking at bootstrap and trying to learn how they do things by taking parts that I need, and along the way learning quite a but about css.

Comment: @ArmenB. Interesting approach. Just make sure to look at `Bootstrap.css` and not the `.min.css` version.

Comment: @TimLewis I'm not looking at the code using plaintext editor, rather using firefox and inspecting elements. That way you can see what css is applied to what.

Comment: @ArmenB. Ah I see. Well best of luck then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property [box-sizing](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

> box-sizing:border-box

To make the value of the padding be included inside the value of the `height`.

**[UpdatedDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqs13o0b/1/)**

Comment: I'm starting to realize that creating CSS is itself a fulltime thing. Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Pushing the body pushes everything that the window displays (the document). I don't recommend it.

Making a div called space and setting it's height to 50px would fix it: so...

The css:

```
   .space {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

The Html:

```
<div class="space"></div>
```

Then you can use it more than once. Put the div after the navigation.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am having hard time figuring out what you mean.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining. Making an element fixed basically takes away it's space and moves the elements under it up on the page. So adding a div that takes up the space of the fixed element moves the other elements back to their original position.

Comment: Ok I tried it and it sorta worked but the scrollbar still poped up when I have extra content underneath.